# Django update same model in different view

Tags: django

I have a book model, where author is many-to-many field:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
  author = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="Task")
  content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

author model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   introduction = models.CharField()
   job_title = models.CharField()
```

In the app of Book, I created a updateview using modelform and UpdateView, this part is easy to do.

```
# example.com/book/1/edit
path('<int:pk>/edit', views.BookEditView.as_view(), name='book-edit')
```

However, in the app of the user, I'd like the user to be able to edit their own books as well:

```
# example.com/user1/book/1/edit
path('<username>/book/<int:pk>/edit', views.UserEditBookView.as_view(), name='editbook')
```

Question:

1. If I use a generic view, can it take two parameters? After all, only one parameter (primary key) is needed to let Django know which one needs to be updated.
2. If I need to use a class-based view, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass through two parameters when using generic view, assuming y already have your forms in `forms.py`

`generic view`:

```
def edit_func(request, pk):
    object = Model.objects.get(your_model_id = pk)
    form = forms.FormName(instance=object)
    context = {'form': form}}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.FormName(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=object)
        if form_up.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('app_name:view_name')
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

And for the `urls.py` you just need to pass `<int:pk>`, it can be `int` or `str`

For class based view you need to define the `get` and the `post` function separately, so it should be something like this:

`class based view`:

```
class EditClass(View):

    def get(self, request, obj_id):
        objMod = ModelName.objects.get(id = obj_id)
        form = New_Object(instance = objMod)
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, "your_template.html", context)

    def post(self, request, obj_id):
        objMod  = ModelName.objects.get(id = obj_id)
        form = New_Object(request.POST, request.FILES , instance=objMod)
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        if(form.is_valid()):
            objMod=form.save(commit=False)
            objMod.save()
            return redirect("your_url_redirect")
        return render(request,"your_template.html", context)
```

For the `urls.py` on class based view:

```
path('edit/<int:obj_id>',views.EditClass.as_view()),
```